Help identifying wire from unknown light switch
I have a near century home that I have been working on and remodeling and down my todo list has been to identify a light switch that doesn't appear to do anything.
I have box with two switches contained in it. The right switch controls an outside light. It is a 3-way switch with another light switch downstairs. The left switch, I have no idea what it does. I've watched a few videos on tone tracing and will be trying this, but I am unsure which wire is my likely wire to my unknown destination.
I have drawn a diagram of what I see behind the switch plate. How can I determine between wires #1, #2, and #3 which head to the outside light, which is connected to the downstairs light switch, and which is my mystery wire?
Drawing of wires, wire nuts, and switches: https://imgur.com/BrDtWeu

I'm guessing that the switch is by a door and it activates a wall outlet in the room. (it could activate only 1/2 of the outlet.)  Code says you must have a light OR an outlet activated by a switch when entering a room.

could control an outdoor plug for Christmas lights

One of the wires connected to your mystery switch should be a constant hot, which you can determine using a multimeter or some such. The other wire would go to the unknown destination, and there is no way to know where that is just by looking at the wires in your switch box. FYI, I could make no sense whatever of your diagram.

This diagram is not adequate to determine much of anything.  You've mislabeled 3 wires when there are 8 wires depicted.
Tone tracing is not even the right idea here.
Start a process of elimination by identifying as many wires as possible.  That means buying a multi-meter, determining which wires are always hot, which wires are switched by the switches, and which wires are truly neutral.

I will assume your diagram contains a slight mistake and you actually have the three white wires connected to the same wirenut and the two black wires on the other wirenut.
If that assumption is true, most likely wire 3 goes to your panel (in a MWBC configuration, so two breakers. One for the black and another for the red.), Wire 1 goes to the downstairs switch (and from there to the outside light) and Wire 2 is the mystery wire to trace.
If my assumption is false and the white from wire 1 is actually connected to the two blacks, then it is possible that Wire 2 goes to the panel, wire 1 to the downstairs switch (as a 3-way switch loop without neutral), the black of Wire 3 goes to the outside light and the red of Wire 3 is your mystery that you need to trace.
Open up your downstairs switch to see how that one is connected (as a loop with the current going in and out on the same cable, or with separate cables for incoming and outgoing). Then you know which wire is controlled by your mystery switch.

Thanks, the diagram was correct so I will be tracing mystery wire 3 based on checking the downstairs switch.

@Oldhome_wiresRVA, Wire 3 is not a complete mystery. You know that the black goes to the outside light, so you can check there if you also have a red that is controlled by the mystery switch. Then you will know if you need to search further in the section before the light or after the light (or that the red is terminated at the light).
